# Solution of Lagrangian

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Could you give me advice how to solve the following Lagrangian?

$$L=x^3+y^3 - \lambda (x^2-xy+y^2-5)$$

$$ \left\{ \begin{array}{c} 
\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = 3x^2 - \lambda (2x-y) = 0
\\\frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = 3y^2 - \lambda (-x+2y) = 0
\\ \frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda} = x^2-xy+y^2=5
\end{array} \right. $$

$$ \left\{ \begin{array}{c} 
3x^2 / (2x-y)= \lambda 
\\ 3y^2 / (-x+2y) = \lambda 
\\  x^2-xy+y^2=5 \Rightarrow x^2 = xy-y^2+5
\end{array} \right. $$

$$\Rightarrow \lambda  = 3x^2 / (2x-y)= 3y^2 / (-x+2y) \Rightarrow x^2 = \frac{(2x-y)(y^2)}{2y-x} \Rightarrow \frac{(2x-y)(y^2)}{2y-x} = xy-y^2+5 \Rightarrow (2x-y)(y^2) = (xy-y^2+5) (2y-x) \Rightarrow 2xy^2 - y^3 = 2xy^2 - 2y^3 +10y - x^2y +xy^2 -5x \Rightarrow  0 =  - y^3 +10y - x^2y +xy^2 -5x $$

I don't know how to transform the above in order to find x,y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First
$$\lambda = \frac{3x^2}{2x-y} = \frac{3y^2}{-x+2y}\implies -x^3 +2x^2y = 2y^2x - y^3.$$
Using the factoring formula for $x^n -y^n$ when $n$ is an odd number:
$$
x^n - y^n = (x-y)(x^{n-1} +  x^{n-2}y + \cdots + xy^{n-2} + y^{n-1}).
$$
Hence we have
$$
x^3 -y^3 + 2y^2x - 2x^2y = 0\implies (x-y)(x^2-xy+y^2) = 0.
$$
I believe you can take it from here.

Comment: $(x-y)\cdot 5=0 \Rightarrow x=y \Rightarrow x^2 -x^2 + x^2 = x^2 = 5 \Rightarrow x = \pm \sqrt(5) = y$

Comment: Thank you, Shuhao! Could you tell me how did you break cubic polynomial? Just a guess?

Comment: $x^3-y^3+2y^2x-2x^2y=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)-2xy(x-y)=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2-2xy)=(x-y)(x^2-xy+y^2)$

Comment: @Igrek No problem, Avatar says it, I used the factoring formula for $x^n - y^n$ when $n$ is an odd number.